# Hide the Has access Panel from users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions

How do I hide the has access panel on the right so users cannot see who all has access. I have setup a document library and have setup individual user folders for users. At the top "Users" folder I have read permissions so people can get access to the their individual folders. But it kind of defeats the purpose if I cant hide the whole has access panel. I see this panel when viewing the folder as a read only user.

[image: Has Access Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it is not feasible for us to hide the details pane by using the out-of-box way.

Meanwhile, to hide the details pane, I recommend you give suggestion in the [feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/) and help to make improvements. Many features of current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback. With requirements like this increase, the problem may well be released in the future. Thanks for your understanding and support.